# Указатели на функии С++

Tags: c++, функции, указатели

Разбираю указатели на функции,и решил реализовать. Функция, сама по себе простенькая, подсчет количества слов в строке.
Но не работает именно указатель на ф-цию, судя из цитаты у меня все правильно,как мне кажеться.
Проблема конкретно в строке `char(*kilsliv)(int);`
Выдает `error: invalid conversion from 'char*' to 'int' [-fpermissive]`
Как исправить, и в чем проблема?Спасибо!

```
> double (*pfunc)( double );
```

В момент этого объявления указатель pfunc

> представляет собой ничего более, как некоторый адрес во внутреннем
>   представлении компьютера (4 байта в 32-бит операционной системе, 8
>   байт в 64-бит операционной системе). Это в точности тот же внутренний
>   вид, который имеет, скажем, указатель на целочисленную переменную
>   int*. Но этот указатель имеет свой строго определённый тип: указатель
>   на функцию, принимающую один параметр типа double, и возвращающую
>   значение типа double. Но вот на какую конкретно функцию указывает
>   указатель, в точке его определения — не важно: значение указателя не
>   определено.
>   [взято отсюда.](http://purecodecpp.com/archives/2301)

```
#include <iostream>
using namespace std;
 int kilsliv(char*strq)
 {
   int q=0;
    for(int i=0;i<20;i++)
    {
      if(strq[i]==' ')
      q+=1;

    }
   return q+1;
 }
int main()
{
    setlocale(LC_ALL, "rus");

    char str[20]="";
    cin.getline(str,20);
    char(*kilsliv)(int);
    cout << str << endl;
 cout<<"kilkist sliv ="<<kilsliv(str)<<endl;
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: Зачем выдумывать? Процитированная ошибка у вас происходит в строке `cout << ...`, а не в строке `char(*kilsliv)(int)`. Отдельно не ясно, при чем здесь этот `int`...

Comment: @Ant,ну из цитаты, я думал что  `int` ето тип того что функция возвращает.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Вот тут:

```
char(*kilsliv)(int);
```

вы объявляете локальный указатель `kilsliv` на функцию, которая принимает `int` и возвращает `char`. Более того это объявление перекрывает функцию из глобальной области видимости. Вот тут:

```
cout<<"kilkist sliv ="<<kilsliv(str)<<endl;
```

вы пытаетесь вызвать функцию по указателю м параметром `char*`, хотя она принимает `int`. Более того этот указатель ничем не был инициализирован. И если у вас даже получится вызвать функцию по этому указателю (например с флагом `-fpermissive` скомпилировав), то скорее всего вы получите `Segmentation fault`, так как указатель ведёт куда-то не туда.
Но можно создать указатель на функцию такую же, как `kilsliv` и инициализировать его:

```
int(*f)(char*) = kilsliv;
```

Теперь при фызове `f()` будет вызывать функция определенная как `kilsliv`, так как это указатели и указывают они теперь на одну область памяти.